# Integration testing in maven not getting executed

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing

I have both a unit test and integration test written both in the same package. The problem is that my unit test gets executed using mvn test but my integration test does not get executed when I use mvn verify. It just executes the unit test.

## pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.study</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration-tests-rnd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>integration-tests-rnd</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>MyIT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

## MyIT.java

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class MyIT extends TestCase {

    public MyIT(String testName) {
        super(testName);
    }

    public static Test suite() {
        return new TestSuite(MyIT.class);
    }

    public void testApp() {
        System.out.println("Integration tests now getting executed because of maven plugin....");
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your full POM or have you excluded any parts of the POM?

Comment: Pretty much! Just one junit dependency setting on top of the existing code snippet that I have posted.

Comment: Just reposted my entire pom settings. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `<pluginManagement/>`, and not `<plugins/>`, your code is declaring the defaults for the failsafe plugin. Declaring the defaults, but not actively describing *IT NEEDS IT*.

Remove the outer `<pluginManagement/>` section and you're set. I mean, this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <!-- your plugin description -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Removed the <pluginManagement/> section but still didn't work.

Comment: Check closely - Here are the files I've used: https://gist.github.com/aldrinleal/8995729

Comment: Copy pasted the code again from your github posting but no success. This is what I see in the failsafe-summary.xml in the fail-safe report directory. <failsafe-summary result="254" timeout="false">
  <completed>0</completed>
  <errors>0</errors>
  <failures>0</failures>
  <skipped>0</skipped>
  <failureMessage/>
</failsafe-summary>